# In Javascript what does <ClassName[]> mean?

Tags: javascript

In this code below, what does `Promise<LetterService[]>` mean?

Is the `LetterService[]` saying create an array with LetterService objects inside it?

What are the <> indicating here?

```
export default interface LetterService {
    GetLetters(): Promise<LetterService[]> }
```

Comment: It's TypeScript https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

Comment: Like VLAZ said, it's TypeScript. And `Promise<LetterService[]>` means a Promise that resolves to an array of `LetterService` instances.